# PHP File Download Links Not Working when filenames brought in from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, download

I'm having some difficulty getting download links to work when they are created via PHP from a MySQL database. The code used to fetch the filenames is as follows (The GET value is for testing; that value will normally come from another web page):

```
$_GET[attachid] = '2597'; //Test value for getting filenames
if(isset($_GET[attachid]) && isset($_GET[UID])) 
  { 
   $attachid = $_GET[attachid];
   $uid = $_GET[UID];
   $sql = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM requisitions.upload WHERE attachId
   ='$attachid'";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($res);

   header("Content-length: $size");
   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   echo $content;
   exit; }
   ?>
```

Next is the code for generating a table of filenames from the MySQL database based on the `attachid`:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT UID, attachId, name FROM requisitions.upload WHERE attachId = 
'$_GET[attachid]'";
$res6 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$name = 'name';
$attachid = 'attachId';
$uid = 'UID';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res6, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
 ?>
  <tr>
<td>
    <?php echo $row['attachId']; ?>
    </td>  

   <td> 
  <?php echo "<a href=quotes.php?attachid={$row['attachId']}&uid={$row['UID']}>
  {$row['name']}</a></td>";
 } </tr></table>
```

The above yields a table with the correct `attachid` and filenames (three, in this case), and each filename appears as a link with the `attachid` and `uid` appended, but when I click on the links, nothing happens. I just get returned to `quotes.php` with no downloads. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? It's like the headers aren't being read. I'm running this on IIS 7, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I see two issues.  You are missing the quotes around your `$_GET` values in the first script and in your second script, you have `$_GET[attachid]` directly in your SQL string instead of adding the variable using `{$_GET['attachid']}`

Comment: You're setting a variable in the URL called `uid`. But you're checking for one called `UID` - it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` is an associative array with named keys. As a result you need to put your key names in quotes when accessing its members.

```
$_GET['attachid'] = '2597'; //Test value for getting filenames
if(isset($_GET['attachid']) && isset($_GET['uid'])) 
  { 
   $attachid = $_GET['attachid'];
   $uid = $_GET['uid'];
   $sql = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM requisitions.upload WHERE attachId
   ='".$attachid."'";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($res);

   header("Content-length: ".$size);
   header("Content-type: ".$type);
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);
   echo $content;
   exit; }
   ?>
```

Keep in mind your code is currently COMPLETELY vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and mysql_* is deprecated. It is **strongly** reccommended to use PDO/prepared statements instead. At the very least escape your `$_GET` variables before using them in the database.

Edit: You also need to concatenate the variables into your headers, before you were just adding the variable name as part of the string. See the code block above.